# Looking for a comic hardback book about an alien ship crashed on earth and a giant humanoid pilot

Tags: story-identification, comics

When I was about 10 I read a great comic hardback.  the story based around the discovery on earth of a crashed alien ship, with a giant human pilot.  I clearly remember a scene where the giant humanoid was on display and scientists on earth were discussing his biology.

There was also a book which needed to be translated and when one of the scientists finally managed to do it, it told the story of three brothers who formed a great city but ultimately fought each other.  The strip had a 1930 to 40s feel and it may have been European, I would love to be able to read it again.

Comment: How "giant" was the humanoid? do you remember anything about the ship (size, shape)?

Answer (score 9):

Could this be "[The Rise and Fall of the Trigan Empire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Trigan_Empire)", AKA "The Trigan Empire"?

Per wikipedia;

> The first strip told of a spaceship crashing into a swamp on Earth,
>   the crew frozen to death, with many written volumes inside in an
>   unknown language. Studies of the crew reveal them to be humanoid, but
>   around 12 feet tall. After many years, the spaceship is turned into
>   the central attraction of an amusement park. Eventually, at a very
>   advanced age, a scientist—Peter Richard Haddon—who had studied the
>   books from the spaceship as a young man manages to decrypt the
>   volumes, and begins to relate the tales.

Comment: If so, this question is a dup of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17393/been-trying-to-find-graphic-novel-for-decades-at-least-i-think-its-a-graphic/17398?s=1|0.3257#17398.